# combine Foundation css grid column definitions for reuse

Tags: html, css, sass, zurb-foundation

In Foundation CSS, you can set the size of columns in a layout like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="bordered small-12 medium-6 large-4 columns">one</div>
  <div class="bordered small-12 medium-6 large-4 columns">two</div>
  <div class="bordered small-12 medium-6 large-4 columns">three</div>
</div>
```

I want to use that particular combination of small, medium, and large sizes in many different places.  Is there a SASS/CSS way to define a class that can be reused throughout my app?

I'd like the above code to look like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="bordered default-size columns">one</div>
  <div class="bordered default-size columns">two</div>
  <div class="bordered default-size columns">three</div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: The answer below worked for me, but you have to ensure that Foundation is included before your custom code and that they are SASSed together.  I was including foundation separately, but I needed to @import it instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SASS, you could use the "extend" feature to combine your classes into one. So, you could do something like:

```
.default-size {
  @extend .small-12;
  @extend .medium-6;
  @extend .large-4;
}
```

See http://sass-lang.com/guide for the extend feature of SASS.

Comment: Thank you!  That worked.  Though, I also had an issue with gulp.  I've updated my question to share that info.

Answer (score 0):

Using Foundation's SASS mixins this is possible:

**HTML**

```
<div class="triple">
  <div>one</div>
  <div>two</div>
  <div>three</div>
</div>
```

**SASS**

```
.triple {
  @include grid-row();

  > div {
    @include grid-column(12);

    @media #{$large-up} { 
      @include grid-column(4); 
    }
  }

}
```

The above will result in 3 stacked columns at the small breakpoint and 3 columns side-by-side at the large breakpoint. You could refactor the HTML markup to remove the `bordered` and `default-size` classes as well in this setup, adding any needed styles to the `> div` selector instead.